# How to save Notepad file into specific folder using autoit lib (Automation Robot Framework)

Tags: automation, robotframework, autoit

I want to save notepad file into a specific folder using autoit lib. Please let me know what to do. I know how to use autoit tool and tried control click as well as mouse click option but need something solid script to do so.
- **I am trying to save file from "Save As" windows**

Comment: Are you writing tests for the notepad application, or is there some other reason you must use notepad?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
       Run("notepad.exe")
       WinWaitActive("Untitled - Notepad")
       WinMenuSelectItem("Untitled - Notepad", "", "&File", "Save &As" )
       Sleep(5000)
       Send("filename")
       Send("{ENTER}",false)
```

For specific folder :

```
       Run("notepad.exe")
       WinWaitActive("Untitled - Notepad")
       WinMenuSelectItem("Untitled - Notepad", "", "&File", "Save &As" )
       Sleep(5000)
       ControlSetText("Save As", "", "[CLASSNN:Edit1]", "D:\Agilent")
       Sleep(2000)
       Send("{ENTER}",false)
       Sleep(2000)
       Send("filename1")
       Send("{ENTER}",false)
```

This is script in autoit ...

Answer (score 0):

If You want to save a file using Robot Framework you can use "Create File" Keyword of "OperatingSystem" Library.

Below is a small example:

```
*** Settings ***
Library             OperatingSystem
*** Test Cases ***
Testing
    Create File           E:\\Test\\newfile.txt        Hello World!!
```

Comment: I am sorry. Actually I am trying to save file into a specific folder from "Save As" window. I have modified the question